# Sybase ASE connetionString is not working without userName/Password

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15, ase

I am using ASE client 15.0.3 version with dot.net version 4.6.2 and able to connect Sybase ASE DB through `connectionString=“Data Source=mango; Port=5000; UID=sa;PWD='abc'; Database='pubs2';”`

Is there any way to connect Sybase ASE DB through windows authentication without uid and pwd in connectionString ? ,the below connectionString is not working getting error “Ase Error: invalid authorization specification”

```
“Data Source=mango; Port=5000; Database='pubs2';IntegratedSecurity = SSPI”
```

or

```
“Data Source=mango; Port=5000; Database='pubs2';IntegratedSecurity = true”
```

Can anyone please suggest?